# boto3.resource(s3) equivalent of boto3.client(s3) get_object_tagging method?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to find a `boto3.resource('s3')` equivalent of

```
s3_connection = boto3.client('s3')
s3_response = client.get_object_tagging()
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=get_object_tagging#S3.Client.get_object_tagging

I have yet to find anything from resource that returns the same information for an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is still opened feature request status. See [This](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1540).